# How to get the selected value of RadioButton in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

So for the previous post I managed to populate my xaml with my desired dynamic control. I have this model holding the property of the control

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ControlType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int? MinNumberValue { get; set; }
    public int? MaxNumberValue { get; set; }
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
```

And in my xaml I have predefined controls then populate some properties base on the model.

```
<Stacklayout Bindable.ItemSource="{Binding ListofControls}">
  <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate x:DataType="survey:ControlModel">
         <Stacklayout>
            <RadioButton CheckChanged="{Binding CheckValueChanged}".... />
         </Stacklayout>
     </DataTemplate>
  </Bindablelayout.ItemTemplate>
</Stacklayout>
```

So the code above is on a nested stacklayout. However, I want to bind my checkchanged method in the RadioButton to get the selected value, but it can't be found. The error says, Method "CheckValueChanged" not found in ControlModel.

```
Public void CheckValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    RadioButton radio = sender as RadioButton;
    var i = radio.Content;
}
```

Can anyone help me about this, cause I'm going do to all other events for the other control type.

Thank you

Comment: "but it can't be found" - please show us the code you are trying and the specific error you are getting.

Comment: @Jason - Hi I edited the main post, I added the complete CheckValueChanged method and the error I got in Xaml.

Comment: you don't use binding syntax with event handlers - just do `CheckChanged="CheckValueChanged"`

Comment: @Jason - But then without using the Binding, the event is not triggered even I change the selected radio button.

Comment: @Jason - This is also the error I got if I directly assign it in CheckChanged event "Eventhandler CheckValueChanged with correct signature not found in type surveypage"

Comment: if your event handler in the page's code-behind?

Comment: @Jason - Yes the CheckValueChanged is in Code Behind. The reason for it is that once I get the selected value, I will save it in the database together with the name of the control

Comment: the error says "with correct **signature** not found" - did you check that you're using the correct signature?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: @Jason - I used the signature into this "(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)", still the same error.

Comment: are you sure the handler is in the code behind of the page, and not the Model or ViewModel?

Comment: @Jason - My bad, code behind of PageViewModel. So should I use the ICommand with this? If it's yes, how I can get the name of the control and its value using ICommand?

Comment: an event handler goes in the code behind of the page (xaml.cs), not the model.  The docs cover both scenarios: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged?view=xamarin-forms